# My app is not able to send message to Teams channel using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to send message to teams channel using graph api. I am able to send the messages using my personal(user) tokens but not able to do it using an app which I have registered in Azure portal. My app also got access to [protected apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis) from Microsft Teams.
Attaching the screen shot of app permissions and code snippet on how I am getting tokens.
[app permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQJzy.png)
[Code snippet to get tokens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WW7kz.png)

One thing I noticed, when I decoded the the tokens I am getting, that roles in tokens only shows application permissions("Teamwork.Migrate.All") and it doesn't show delegated permissions("ChannelMessage.Read.All","ChannelMessage.Send","Teamwork.Migrate.All").

Below are the error message I am getting.

1. While doing get request to [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teams_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteams_id%7D/channels/%7Bchannel_id%7D/messages)

```
one of 'ChannelMessage.Read.All' or 'ChannelMessage.Read.Group' when using resont. Roles on the request 'Teamwork.Migrate.All' and resource specific consent g request ''", 'innerError': {'date': '2021-07-04T14:27:41', 'request-id': '8c1f-e345bf15da7b', 'client-request-id': '8c1fffc2-c94d-4d5b-a81d-e345bf15da7b'}}}
```

2. While doing post request to [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teams_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages/{message-id}/replies](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteams_id%7D/channels/%7Bchannel_id%7D/messages/%7Bmessage-id%7D/replies)
   `{'error': {'code': 'Unauthorized', 'message': 'Unauthorized', 'innerError': {'d4:26:47', 'request-id': '44fe99be-1ed8-4505-a3e7-a88ce934e3f8', 'client-request8-4505-a3e7-a88ce934e3f8'}}}`

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta)(Application permission). Application permissions are only supported for [migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams). Instead you should try delegated flow:  [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-beta). Please go though the documentation and you can try it using Postman or Fiddler.

You can also try [Get started with Microsoft Graph and Python](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/python) tutorial which shows fetching calendar information using Graph APIs.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to do it using delegated workflow.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you. It will help others also.